# excel conditional formatting comparing different rows and columns

Tags: excel

I'd like to change background color of cells if the value of `$E2=$F1` (comparing different row and column). The range I have selected is `=$E:$F`.
I want the background color changed in both same value cells or at least on the first column cell. The problem is that I don't know of to tell excel to change the "1st. column, 2nd. row" of every comparison. Excel is changing only the cells of the first row and not the cells that have the same value.

[Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWVZE.jpg)
[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcxRF.jpg)

I don't speak English, I hope you can understand what I am saying. :-)

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom formula rule as `=$E1=$F1`, and apply it to the range `=$E:$F`.

Be careful that this will see two blank cells as equals and turn them red, so you're better off doing `=$E3=$F3` applied to the range `=$E3:$F12`.

**EDIT**

Now I understand your question, just create two different rules,

1. `=$E4=$F3` applied to range `=$E4:$E12`
2. `=$E4=$F3` applied to range `=$F3:$F12`

Comment: Thank you @tim-wilkinson 
Actually I want to compare column E value with previous row column F value so I use '=$E2=$F1' and it works. The problem is that when excel applies the format, changes the backgroud color of 'E1' cell and 'F1' cell. I want to format the cells that are equal, 'E2' and 'F1' (or in my sheet 'E9' and 'F8')

Comment: Ah ok, see my edit, just create two of the same rule but for applied to each column.

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked!!! If anyone want to know, the formulas I finally used are `=AND($E2=$F1;$C2=$C1;NOT(ISBLANK($F1)))` and `=AND($E2=$F1;$C2=$C1;NOT(ISBLANK($E2)))`.  And applied to ranges `=$F$1:$F$1000` and `=$E$2:$E$1000`respectively.